# Java - Regex - Allow 0-9, periods, hypen

Tags: java, regex

I cant build the right regex.

Valid:

- 1.1.1
- 1.1-1
- 1-1.1
- 1-1-1
- 1-1
- 1.1

Invalid:

- 1..1
- 1.
- 1--1
- 1-

so far i got

```
^[0-9]+[0-9.-][0-9]+$
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Try something like this: `([0-9]+[.-])*[0-9][.-]?` (Methods `matches()` do full match, `^$` are not required for them.)

Comment: Giving examples is not sufficient. You have to specify your rules.

Comment: @EJP He put down the regex he is currently using and that doesn't work for him. All of that nicely formatted. What else do you expect here? I think this is a nice question for a newbie.

Comment: @GhostCat If the RE he is using doesn't work, it doesn't correctly specify the rules he needs. Neither do the examples. What is expected is what I said: the rules. A specification. Examples cannot possibly deliver that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `^[0-9]+[0-9.-][0-9]+$` pattern matches a string that fully matches the pattern: 1 or more digits (`[0-9]+`), a digit or `.` or `-` (`[0-9.-]`) and then 1  or more digits (`[0-9]+`). It can match consecutive `-` or/and `.` inside a string of digits.

You may use

```
^[0-9]+(?:[.-][0-9]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GnrpaK/1)

If you use it in the `.matches()` method, the `^` and `$` anchors can be omitted.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+`  - 1 or more (the `+` quantifier matches *1 or more occurrences*, if you only need to match a *single occurrence* remove the `+` quantifier) digits
- `(?:[.-][0-9]+)*` - zero or more consecutive sequences of

  - `[.-]` - a `.` or `-`
  - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits (the same quantifier note as above applies)
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

This here should do:

```
^[0-9]([.-][0-9])*$
```

One digit, followed by zero or more occurrences of (dot/minus digit)

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on other answers.
You did not indicate the case of a lone digit without period and hyphen:

1. (invalid)
   1- (invalid)
   1  (I have assumed this case is invalid)

Also this regex only allows single digits (e.g. 2.2.2, not 22.22.22)

```
    ^\d([.-]\d)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
^[0-9]([.-][0-9])*$
```

and

```
^[0-9]+(?:[.-][0-9]+)*$
```

works. Thanks